# Filtering results of a nested association based on the count of a deeper association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have the following models and associations:

```
class ClassProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :enrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :student_profiles, through: :enrollments

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student_profile
  belongs_to :class_profile

class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :enrollment, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :class_profile, through: :enrollment
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :parent_profiles, through: :relationships

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student_profile
  belongs_to :parent_profile

class ParentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationships
  has_many :student_profiles, through: :relationships
```

What I want to do is define a method like the one below for ClassProfile

```
class ClassProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def orphans
    #return a collection of all student_profiles where
    #there are no parent_profiles associated
    #(i.e. parent_profiles.count = 0 or parent_profiles.empty? = true
  end
```

I'd like to do this, if possible, with a single statement where I don't have to write a loop that manually queries each student_profile. Is there a way to do this, and if so, what is it?

**Update**
To clarify: I do have a method in `StudentProfile` as shown below:

```
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  def child?
    self.relationships[0].present?
  end
```

And so I'd like to use a method like this:

```
class ClassProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def orphans
    self.student_profiles.where( child? == false )
  end
```

That is, a single statement that returns the proper collection. But this is not a valid use of `where` and throws an error. Which makes sense because as far as I can tell, the `where` method on an associated model only works on fields, not methods. Anyway, this is the kind of thing I'm looking for, only something that is actually valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Here's the code that has the desired behavior:

```
  def orphans
    student_profiles.reject { |s| s.child? }
  end
```

I believe this needs to iterate through all the student profiles (as opposed to something that works at the query level), but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do a join for this. In the ClassProfile

```
    def orphans
      self.joins(student_profiles: :relationships)
    end
```

The join here is an inner join. Students with no relationships will not be joined here. Moreover, maybe you can try a better name for your methods. Your naming is quite ambiguous.